# Degree of belief in fuzzy modelling

Tags: probability, bayesian, fuzzy

I’ was reading a paper on fuzzy regression. In that paper, and many other papers on fuzzy regression, the authors use most of the time a $h$ to indicate a certain degree of belief. Unfortunately the authors do not clarify what the meaning is of degree of belief given for instance a coefficient.

I have read some papers on the degree of belief, and it seems that it has several meanings in different areas (Bayesian, Fuzzy modelling etc.). I’m drowning in definitions, mathematical and philosophical debates.

Q1: How to interpret, understand, the degree of belief in Fuzzy modelling? (Using the example $h=0$ for $y=1+3x$ and $h=.5$ for $y=1+4x$

In one paper the degree of belief $h$ whas compared to fit of the data (?!)

Q2: Is there, in "classical" statistics, a similarity of degree of belief?

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the number in fuzzy logics means a degree of membership (quantifying to what extent something belongs to some class). An example could be a somewhat cloudy sky, and you say the weather is somewhat sunny.

This is not to be confused with a probability. Here the number means the extent to which something might happen (or the degree to which some agent thinks something is true; we're now talking about Bayesian probabilities here). An example can be person claiming "I think it will rain tomorrow with a 90 percent certainty.". Note that we are dealing with a binary proposition (either it rains, or it doesn't rain), although the probability of the variable being true is a real number between 0 and 1. And here 0.75 doesn't mean it will rain *more* than at 0.25, it's just more likely that it rains at all.

Note that both concepts can be combined. For example you can have uncertainty over the degree of sunniness of the weather. Maybe you're sitting in the basement and only get some indirect sunlight. Then you have a probability distribution over a continuous variable in the intervall $[0,1]$ (like a uniform distribution, or a truncated Gaussian).

However, using my interpretation it doesn't make sense to call the number in fuzzy logics "degree of belief".